# Are there any Endothermic Pyrophoric Substances?

Tags: thermodynamics, reactivity

I've recently been reading about pyrophoric materials, specifically as they relate to rocketry, and this made me curious if there are any substances which are the complete opposite of pyrophoric. Essentially, are there any materials which react on contact with air (i.e. either gaseous nitrogen or oxygen), but *endothermically*? If so, do they react at STP, or only under special circumstances?

Comment: Pyrophoric is not the correct word; pyro means fire and such would very likely have to be exothermic unless you have very hot air.

Comment: @ChemBird, yes, I understand that's the case. What I'm trying to ascertain is whether there are any substances which will react on contact with air (like pyrophoric substances do), but endothermically rather than exothermically. I.e., they still react on contact, but consume energy rather than release it.